# symfony2 doctrine repeated data

Tags: symfony-2.3

I'm developing a simple application with symfony 2.3. I have a table called "state" in which there are 4 records:

Id            Name
(tinyint)   (varchar(30))

```
  1     Single
  2     Married
  3     Widowed
  4     Divorced
```

I use the following instruction:

```
$state = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('appBDDBundle:State')->findAll();
```

The twig:

```
{% for s in state %}  
    {{ s.name }}  
{% endfor %}
```

And returns me this:

```
Single  
Single  
Single  
Single
```

¿What happened? I'm new in symfony 2

Greetings and thanks.

Edited:
The controller:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $state = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('appBDDBundle:State')->findAll();
    return $this->render('appAdminBundle:States:index.html.twig', array('state' => $state));
}
```

Edited:
I solved:

They should put in big letters and bold: **"DON'T USE THE TINYINT DATA TYPE AS PRIMARY KEY BECAUSE SYMFONY CONSIDERED AS BOOLEAN TYPE AND THIS MAY CAUSE ERRORS"**

Comment: Looks exactly like it should. You sure this is your **actual** code and that the DB in use by the app does in fact have four different values? Can you show more of the controller code, ie how you assign `$state` to the view?

Comment: I'd debug it and put a breakpoint on the second line of your controller action to inspect the values of `$state` (or just use `var_dump($state); exit;`). Are you using a custom repository for your `State` models?